# where is my jquery installed if i use npm in vscode

Tags: jquery, npm

I installed jquery to use it. However, I cannot find the location of jquery that I have installed. where is my jquery and how do I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery will be present under `/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` (minified version) if installed locally

Answer (score 0):

If you used npm or yarn to install it, this will be inside the node_modules folder.

Comment: I see jquery.js in both node_modules/dist folder and node_modules/src folder... which one should i use

Comment: Use `const $ = require('jquery')`. But if you need file dist folder is for production usage.